# How can i scroll my parent listview with the child scroll view, and also is there any way to stop the parent scroll to a particular level?

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter and was experimenting with ListView Builder(PostGridScreen), inside a ListView and got into a problem. In the end of my List of PostGridScreen, some part of the last List Tile is hidden and to make it visible i have to scroll my ListView from Above. Once the Parent List View is scrolled, i can't get it back.

Is their any way by which i can scroll this listview with children Text Welcome with the ListView i have in my PostGridScreen. And also is there any way by which i can stop the scroll at the tab bar titles.

```
ListView(
        
        children: [
          
          Text("Welcome"),
          
          TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            isScrollable: true,
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 45),
            unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xFFCDCDCD),
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Text('Tab1'),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text('Tab2'),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text('Tab3'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 120.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
                PostGridScreen(type: "Type1"),
                PostGridScreen(type: "Type2"),
                PostGridScreen(type: "Type3"),
              ]))
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the top Widget in this case should be a `Column`, which vertically aligns the children. Then each `TabBarView` can be a `ListView`.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Text('Welcome'),
    TabBar(...),
    // expanded fills the remaining screen area
    Expanded(
      child: Container(...)
    )
)
```

Comment: You meant Expanded. Thanks for your help it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question could you send a gif of the issue or a way to recreate this